# Using C++ data in Python?

Tags: python, c++, sockets, falcon

I am using novint falcon a haptic device and this device is not supported in python. Since my boss wants the coordinate value of x y z which are in C++ to send my code of python. In simple words sending the data from the C++ program to the python program.

Comment: What is your question? Can you make a [mcve] of what you've tried so far? Why the C tag when all you talk about is C++ (and python)?

Comment: If your device doesn't support Python, where does your Python code run ? How do you plan to "send" the data from C++ to Python?

Comment: the scenario is not clear, define "sending the data"?
the easiest way would be: expose the C++ function to C and use ctypes in python to make a function call.

Comment: @Hugal31 The plan seems to be to use [tag:sockets].

Comment: [libnifalcon](https://github.com/libnifalcon/libnifalcon) - "_SWIG bindings (requires SWIG and whatever language bindings you want to use)

`FalconBridge` proxy class for accessing the falcon from other languages. Tested with Java and **Python** so far._"

Comment: the easiest way to interface between c++ and python is [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)